# Mongodb or SQLite in my current situation

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, sqlite

I have two entities or two documents, which needs to have the respective attributes:

1. _id, instruction: json, index: Number, mac: String;
2. id, packageId: Number, version: Number, description: json;

In my situation the database will not scale so much, the max number of each entity or document will be something like 10000.

I not read/write so frequently, the max number I believe is about 300/min.

My Only goal is performance, I need to choose between SQLite or Mongodb.  I already searched performance comparison between both, but the conclusion is always 'depends on situation', which database I choose in my situation?

obs: I am running a nodejs application.

Comment: Are the instruction documents and package documents related / referenced to each other? Is there a relationship / reference between them?

Comment: @DhruvShah no, theres is no relation between the documents.

Comment: This feels like a question that is going to attract more opinion based answers than concrete answers. Can you reword it? Questions seeking opinions get closed.

Comment: @JasonAller Sorry but i think this will not attract opinion based answers, my question was very clear, i want a specific solution for a specific case.
edit: Of course the possible answers will have a little opinion related because everyone do that intentionally or unintentionally and i will always consider this as well.